Java features only available with source level 22 and above in VS Code

So here it is showing me an error for this.
I changed the Configure Runtime for projects, but it is not still changing...

I have changed the version but it is still not changing and showing me the same message

make sure you also restart the VS code application

Post text rather than images.

Pardon me, but I can't read the text in the images in your question because of the small size and the different colors. Can you [edit] your question and post the Java code and the error message as text?

I have go to the setting and then type Configure Runtime for Projects.
enter image description here
Then after this I have change
enter image description here
Setting to the current name and path of the new jdk we want to change as your wish this will help I guess!!
